# Como posso fazer com que o regex reconheça "resultados parciais" em JavaScript para mascarar uma input?

Tags: javascript, regex, mask

Estou fazendo uma `<input>` com máscara, formatando conforme o usuário digita. Nesse caso, é uma entrada de CNPJ.

Um Regex para formatar o CNPJ seria `/(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})\.?(\d{3})\/?(\d{4})-?(\d+)/g`, porém assim ele formata somente quando o Regex é completamente satisfeito (com todos os grupos de número tendo algum valor não vazio). Execute o código abaixo para visualizar essa situação.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#cnpj');

function onTextChanged(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  const pureText = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  const textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})\.?(\d{3})\/?(\d{4})-?(\d+)/g,
      '$1.$2.$3/$4-$5'
    );
  document.querySelector('#cnpj').value = textMasked;
}

input.addEventListener('input', onTextChanged);


// Automatizando a entrada de dados para exemplificação aqui no Snippet
// Código adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617675/8839059
const time = 150;
let current = 0;
let cnpjText = '12345678000123'

function writeText() {
  const newValue = input.value + cnpjText[current];
  const ev = new Event('input');

  input.value = newValue;
  input.dispatchEvent(ev);
  if (current < cnpjText.length - 1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(writeText, time);
  } else {
  }
}
setTimeout(writeText, time);
```

```html
<input id="cnpj" maxLength="18" />
```

Eu consigo lidar com essa situação colocando alguns `if`'s para as "partes" do Regex:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#cnpj');

function onTextChanged(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  const pureText = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  let textMasked = '';
  if (pureText.length <= 2) {
    textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})/g,
      '$1'
    );
  } else if (pureText.length <= 5) {
    textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})\.?(\d+)/g,
      '$1.$2'
    );
  } else if (pureText.length <= 8) {
    textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})\.?(\d+)/g,
      '$1.$2.$3'
    );
  } else if (pureText.length <= 12) {
    textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})\.?(\d{3})\/?(\d+)/g,
      '$1.$2.$3/$4'
    );
  } else {
    textMasked = pureText.replace(
      /(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})\.?(\d{3})\/?(\d{4})-?(\d+)/g,
      '$1.$2.$3/$4-$5'
    );
  }
  document.querySelector('#cnpj').value = textMasked;
}

input.addEventListener('input', onTextChanged);


// Automatizando a entrada de dados para exemplificação aqui no Snippet
// Código adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617675/8839059
const time = 150;
let current = 0;
let cnpjText = '12345678000123'

function writeText() {
  const newValue = input.value + cnpjText[current];
  const ev = new Event('input');

  input.value = newValue;
  input.dispatchEvent(ev);
  if (current < cnpjText.length - 1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(writeText, time);
  } else {
  }
}
setTimeout(writeText, time);
```

```html
<input id="cnpj" maxLength="18" />
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é como fazer algo mais genérico para não precisar de tantos `if`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua função você faz `replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`, o que já elimina todos os caracteres que não forem números. Isso quer dizer que na regex não precisa ter `\.?`, nem `\/?` e muito menos `-?`, pois como os caracteres que não são dígitos já foram removidos, então colocar qualquer outra coisa na regex se torna redundante e desnecessário.

Dito isso, a solução com regex não é lá muito "bonita" (inclusive no final tem outra sem regex, o que eu acho que é melhor para este caso), pois envolve verificar se cada uma das partes está na string. Ou seja, a string pode ser:

- apenas 2 dígitos
- 2 dígitos, seguidos de 1 a 3 dígitos (caso em que eu coloco um ponto depois do segundo dígito)
- 2 dígitos, seguidos de 3 dígitos, seguidos de 1 a 3 dígitos (caso em que eu coloco um ponto depois do segundo dígito e outro ponto depois do quinto)
- e assim por diante...

Ou seja, se eu fosse verificar apenas o primeiro e segundo casos acima, a regex seria algo como `/(\d{2})(\d{1,3})?/` - o trecho `\d{1,3}` (1 a 3 dígitos) é opcional (ou ainda `\d{0,3}`, por exemplo).

Para verificar também o terceiro caso, ficaria `/(\d{2})(?:(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?)?/` - agora eu tenho `(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?` (1 a 3 dígitos seguidos opcionalmente por 1 a 3 dígitos) - e todo este trecho também é opcional. Detalhe que agora eu usei um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (o trecho `(?:etc)`), assim eu não crio grupos a mais (que são as variáveis `$1`, `$2`, etc, que você usa no `replace`). Se eu não usasse `(?:` nos parênteses, seria criado outro grupo à toa.

Aplicando esta lógica para todos os casos, ficaria esse monstro:

```
^(\d{2})(?:(\d{1,3})(?:(\d{1,3})(?:(\d{1,4})(\d{1,2})?)?)?)?$
```

Eu também uso os [marcadores](http://regularexpressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (início e fim da string), para garantir que a string tem só o que está especificado pela regex (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos).

E para fazer a substituição, eu uso uma [função de *callback*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), que recebe como parâmetro todos os grupos de captura. Assim, eu posso verificar se o grupo foi encontrado pela regex (como eles correspondem a partes opcionais, nem sempre terão um valor). Ficaria assim:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#cnpj');

let regex = /^(\d{2})(?:(\d{1,3})(?:(\d{1,3})(?:(\d{1,4})(\d{1,2})?)?)?)?$/;

// de g1 a g5 são os grupos de captura
function replacement(match, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5) {
    let s = '';
    // se o grupo está presente, adiciona na string
    if (g1) s += g1;
    if (g2) s += `.${g2}`;
    if (g3) s += `.${g3}`;
    if (g4) s += `/${g4}`;
    if (g5) s += `-${g5}`;
    return s;
}

function onTextChanged(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  const pureText = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  let textMasked = pureText.replace(regex, replacement);
  document.querySelector('#cnpj').value = textMasked;
}

input.addEventListener('input', onTextChanged);

const time = 150;
let current = 0;
let cnpjText = '12345678000123'

function writeText() {
  const newValue = input.value + cnpjText[current];
  const ev = new Event('input');

  input.value = newValue;
  input.dispatchEvent(ev);
  if (current < cnpjText.length - 1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(writeText, time);
  }
}
setTimeout(writeText, time);
```

```html
<input id="cnpj" maxLength="18" />
```

De qualquer forma, veja que não dá para escapar do "monte de `if`'s", pois você precisa verificar se um grupo está presente para saber se coloca ou não os separadores (hífen, ponto ou barra).

---

Mas será que precisa mesmo dessa regex complicada? Você poderia por exemplo eliminar os caracteres que não são números e formatar o valor usando o bom e velho [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#cnpj');

function onTextChanged(e) {
  const text = e.target.value;
  const pureText = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  let textMasked = pureText.slice(0, 2);
  if (pureText.length > 2) {
    textMasked += '.' + pureText.slice(2, 5);
  }
  if (pureText.length > 5) {
    textMasked += '.' + pureText.slice(5, 8);
  }
  if (pureText.length > 8) {
    textMasked += '/' + pureText.slice(8, 12);
  }
  if (pureText.length > 12) {
    textMasked += '-' + pureText.slice(12);
  }
  document.querySelector('#cnpj').value = textMasked;
}

input.addEventListener('input', onTextChanged);

const time = 150;
let current = 0;
let cnpjText = '12345678000123'

function writeText() {
  const newValue = input.value + cnpjText[current];
  const ev = new Event('input');

  input.value = newValue;
  input.dispatchEvent(ev);
  if (current < cnpjText.length - 1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(writeText, time);
  }
}
setTimeout(writeText, time);
```

```html
<input id="cnpj" maxLength="18" />
```

Talvez você não ache a solução boa por "usar vários `if`'s", e até daria para generalizar, criando um array contendo as posições em que é feito o `slice` e o caractere usado para separar as partes - algo assim:

```
let sliceData = [ {size: 2, sep:''}, {size: 3, sep: '.'}, {size: 3, sep: '.'}, {size: 4, sep: '/'}, {size: 2, sep: '-'}];
let textMasked = '';
let index = 0;
for (const s of sliceData) {
    textMasked += s.sep + pureText.slice(index, index + s.size);
    index += s.size;
    if (pureText.length <= index) break;
}
```

Mas sinceramente acho que não precisa dessa complicação, se o único objetivo é se livrar de uns `if`'s.

Comment: Ótima resposta. De fato havia "lixo" no Regex pois eu estava tentando muitas coisas diferentes e acabou passando despercebido. Inclusive, eu estava dando uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580048/8839059) do SOen que falava sobre *partial matching*, estava querendo "generalizar" para criar um componente que aceitasse qualquer tipo de máscara, mas percebi que não valeria o custo benefício de fato, seriam Regex muito complexos e talvez lentos de executar (não cheguei a analisar a performance)

Comment: @RafaelTavares Em geral regex é mais lento, já que a expressão precisa ser compilada (isso mesmo, compilada!), é gerada uma estrutura interna que a *engine* usará para executar, os matches e grupos de captura tem que ser gerados, o que consome memória, etc. Claro que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será imperceptível, mas de qq forma vale testar para os seus casos de uso e ver se chega a ser um problema de performance (e vale avaliar tb o custo de manutenção, já que a regex da resposta não é lá muito fácil de entender e manter, na minha opinião)